# Flyway migration stalls at 0%

Tags: sql-server, gradle, flyway

I am trying to install an initial flyway migration to a database through gradle. The script is generated via SQL Server Management Studio from an existing database, and the script runs fine in SSMS, here is the flyway info before I try to migrate.

```
:flywayInfo                                                        
+---------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version | Description   | Installed on        | State   |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1       | Initial Setup |                     | Pending |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
```

but flywayMigrate does this and then sits at 0% until my patience runs out and I kill it.

```
:flywayMigrate                                                        
DB: Changed database context to 'master'. (SQL State: S0001 - Error Code: 5701)
> Building 0% > :flywayMigrate
```

Any clues as to what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the flywaydb documentation is wrong when it says "DDL exported by SQL Server can be used unchanged in a Flyway migration."

I cleaned it up and reduced it to just create tables and indexes and it worked.

Comment: My guess is that the original SQL script did things like connect to the database/schema and logged in. These would have cause problems for flyway as it will have already done this as it created its connection. "Error 5701" is not normally considered an 'error' as it is an 'informational message' that indicates that a database has been selected.